# Pyforms - Form appears always maximized

Tags: python

When I run my script, the main form pops-up maximized (i.e. taking all the space on my screen). I tried to set the height and width of the form using the CSS file but it did not work. I haven't seen anything about it elsewhere.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import pyforms
from pyforms import BaseWidget
from pyforms.Controls import ControlText
from pyforms.Controls import ControlButton
from pyforms.Controls import ControlFile
class ImportIntoFile(BaseWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(ImportIntoFile,self).__init__('HTCondor & EnergyPlus')

    self._Input     = ControlFile('Input')
    self._Output    = ControlFile('Output')
    self._Import    = ControlButton('Import')
    self._Close     = ControlButton('Close')

    self._formset = ['',('  ','_Input','  '),('  ','_Output','  '),('','_Close','','_Import',''),'']

    self._Import.value = self.__ImportAction
    self._Close.value = self.__CloseAction

def __ImportAction(self):
    OutputFile = open(self._Output.value,'a')       
    InputFile = open(self._Input.value,'r')

    OutputFile.close
    InputFile.close

def __CloseAction(self):
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":   pyforms.startApp( ImportIntoFile )`
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a short example of a script that behaves this way? See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a good solution too. For temporary workaround when I want to avoid maximized by default, what I did is modifying C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyforms\gui\standaloneManager.py.

From

```
if geometry is not None:
    w.show()
    w.setGeometry(*geometry)
else:
    w.showMaximized()
```

To

```
if geometry is not None:
    w.show()
    w.setGeometry(*geometry)
else:
    w.showNormal()
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you for sharing that. I didn't think to look in the code ... Have you thought about submitting a change to the source code (https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms/blob/master/pyforms/gui/standaloneManager.py)?

Answer (score 9):

You can pass a window geometry to the `pyforms.start_app()` call. So something like the code below should work.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyforms.start_app( ImportIntoFile, geometry=(200, 200, 400, 400) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Pyforms uses Qt, [so some of these modules will be familiar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtgui-module.html), and [this css will modify them](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html).

I used:

```
QMainWindow{
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:500px;
}
```

to successfully set the size of the main window, but you can't increase the size later, so if all you want is a fixed size window, it works.